# GRE Tunnel to localhost

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, tunnel

I am trying to use a GRE Tunnel (or TAP) to connect a local Linux network namespace light weight VM to the local HOST machine. It all *appears* to work except that replies from the host do not make it back to the VM.

My setup:

HOST real IP: `10.1.101.101/24`

HOST GRE (Setup like so):

```
ip l add dev gre1 type gretap remote 10.1.101.101 local 10.1.101.101 key 101
ip a add dev gre1 10.201.0.2/24
ip l set dev gre1 up
```

HOST Network config:

```
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:30:1b:42:65:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.101.101/24 brd 10.1.101.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::230:1bff:fe42:65ac/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:04:d0:50:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

82: gre0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
83: gretap0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1462 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
84: gre1@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65494 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e2:83:0d:a4:cc:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.201.0.2/24 scope global gre1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e083:dff:fea4:cc23/64 scope link tentative dadfailed 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

HOST routes:

```
ip r
default via 10.1.101.1 dev eth0 
10.1.101.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.101.101 
10.201.0.0/24 dev gre1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.201.0.2 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
```

HOST iptables is blank (IE: `iptables -F`)

VM Network config:

```
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: gre0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: gretap0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1462 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
114: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:aa:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.201.0.1/24 brd 10.201.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::200:ff:feaa:0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

VM routes:

```
ip r
10.201.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.201.0.1
```

Now ping the HOST `10.201.0.2` from the VM `10.201.0.1` and capture packets:

`tcpdump -ni gre1` on the HOST:

```
11:57:36.379404 ARP, Request who-has 10.201.0.2 tell 10.201.0.1, length 28
11:57:36.379431 ARP, Reply 10.201.0.2 is-at e2:83:0d:a4:cc:23, length 28
11:57:36.379455 ARP, Reply 10.201.0.2 is-at e2:83:0d:a4:cc:23, length 28
11:57:37.376634 ARP, Request who-has 10.201.0.2 tell 10.201.0.1, length 28
11:57:37.376658 ARP, Reply 10.201.0.2 is-at e2:83:0d:a4:cc:23, length 28
11:57:37.376683 ARP, Reply 10.201.0.2 is-at e2:83:0d:a4:cc:23, length 28
11:57:38.376539 ARP, Request who-has 10.201.0.2 tell 10.201.0.1, length 28
11:57:38.376567 ARP, Reply 10.201.0.2 is-at e2:83:0d:a4:cc:23, length 28
11:57:38.376596 ARP, Reply 10.201.0.2 is-at e2:83:0d:a4:cc:23, length 28
```

`tcpdump -ni eth0` on the VM:

```
11:57:36.379243 ARP, Request who-has 10.201.0.2 tell 10.201.0.1, length 28
11:57:37.376384 ARP, Request who-has 10.201.0.2 tell 10.201.0.1, length 28
11:57:38.376384 ARP, Request who-has 10.201.0.2 tell 10.201.0.1, length 28
```

So, AFAICS the VM sends ARP Request to HOST, HOST answers ARP (Correctly) but the ARP packet does not make it back across the GRE tunnel ?

Note 1: The VM is created by a product called [CORE Emulator](https://www.nrl.navy.mil/itd/ncs/products/core) and consists of a *basic router* attached to a *GRE Node*, this node points to `10.1.101.101` and the key is 101

Note 2: If, instead of using Core Emulator locally I run it on a different machine but with all the same settings the same configuration works properly (using 10.1.101.101).

I have also tried setting the HOST GRE Tunnel to:

```
ip l add gre1 type gretap remote 127.0.0.1 local 127.0.0.1 key 101
```

and the VM *GRE node* to point to `127.0.0.1`

but I get the same result, ARP is seen and replied to by the HOST but **not** seen by the VM.

EDIT 1:
In answer to my "real world" problem, CORE does provide me with a suitable solution as described here: https://downloads.pf.itd.nrl.navy.mil/docs/core/core-html/usage.html#other-methods

EDIT 2: Subsequent question ?
Is it possible for a "Linux Container / Network namespace / LXC" etc VM to communicate with the HOST machine via a GRE tunnel. The GRE tunnel endpoints would be something like `HOST:127.0.0.1` to `VM:?.?.?.?` (Those question marks lead me to the conclusion that while the VM may be able to send to 127.0.0.1 the HOST does not have a return path to the VM, which could be why the ARP, in my initial question, does not get through to the VM).

Thanks for taking the time to read this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: A GRE tunnel works on top of a normal connection, and gives you an additional network interface, which adds/removes the tunnel headers in the network packets.

So the normal setup to make a tunnel between two machines A and B is the following:

1) Check that A and B have "normal" IP addresses and can see each other. E.g., if A has IP "10.0.0.1/24" on its `eth0` and B has IP IP "10.0.0.2/24" on its `eth0`, do a `ping 10.0.0.2` on A and a `ping 10.0.0.1` on B.

2) Add a tunnel device on A with the local IP of A and the remote IP of B, add a new IP to the interface:

```
ip link add dev gre0 type gretap remote 10.0.0.2 local 10.0.0.1 key 123
ip addr add 10.0.44.1/24 dev gre0 
ip link set gre0 up
```

3) The same for B, with the appropriate IP addresses:

```
ip link add dev gre0 type gretap remote 10.0.0.1 local 10.0.0.2 key 123
ip addr add 10.0.44.2/24 dev gre0
ip link set gre0 up
```

4) Do `ping 10.0.44.2` on A, and `ping 10.0.44.1` on B to see if the tunnel works.

As you can see, this is not the setup you have: Your local and remote address for the tunnel on HOST is the same, there is no local and remote address for the tunnel on VM, the tunnel interfaces on the VM are down, and the IP address that belongs to the tunnel has ended up on `eth0`. None of this really makes sense, so it's no surprise it doesn't work.

I don't know how the Core Emulator handles "GRE Nodes", but from the configuration you've shown, this seems just to be a layer for configuring the GRE interface. So either figure out how the Core Emulator handles those, or forget about the "GRE Nodes" in the emulator, and configure it manually.

Even better, as an exercise, configure *two* VMs A and B which are connected in the Core Emulator, and then add the GRE tunnels manually as described above. This is a symmetrical situation, and should be the least confusing.

Comment: Hi, I tried your "Exercise" first and it does setup a simple GRE tunnel between two VMs (A & B) and both ends are ping-able etc. I have to look deeper into the "CORE" problem. I will also add further details to the original question.

Comment: FYI: `ip add dev gre0 foo` should be `ip addr add dev gre0 foo` .. my edit of your post was rejected.